# Custom min/max word count validator in Angular 1.3+?

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'd like to create a pair of custom word count validators in Angular 1.3+ to which I can pass min/max values, e.g. something like the following:

```
<input type=text min-word-count="10" max-word-count="200">
```

I gather from the [official documentation on the subject](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation) that a custom directive similar to the following integer example should be an appropriate fit:

```
app.directive('integer', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.integer = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }

        if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }

        // it is invalid
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

However, I'm not sure how to customize this example in order to pass custom values to it on the fly.

What is the best practice for passing values to a custom validation directive like the one above?

Comment: The values are available in `attrs` in this example. You can use `attrs.minWordCount` and `attrs.maxWordCount` to get your parameters. If you want to pass computed values instead of static values, you can set up a scope and bind to them using `=` (see the angular Scope help for details).

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive('maxWordCount', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

        //For DOM -> model validation
        var maxLimit = attrs.maxWordCount;
        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value){

            var valid = true;

            if(value){
                valid = value.split(' ').length <= maxLimit;
            }

            ctrl.$setValidity('maxWordCount', valid);
            return valid ? value : undefined;
        });

        //For model -> DOM validation
        ctrl.$formatters.unshift(function(value) {

            var valid = true;

            if(value){
                valid = value.split(' ').length <= maxLimit;
            }

            ctrl.$setValidity('maxWordCount',valid);
            return value;
        });

    }
};
});
```